# Are there issues with making a ldap database group readable?

Tags: backup, permissions, login

I'm managing several CentOS 6.5 machines using ldap and kerberos for user accounts and authentication. I want to back up the ldap database as well as other root owned files stored on *server1* to *server2* using rsnapshot. Since the backup will be cron scheduled, I need to be able to login to *server1* without a password and copy protected data. As far as I know, I have a few options:

1. Create an ssh keypair for the root user

   (I’d rather not do this since I’m already using kerberos for authentication)
2. Use a kerberos principal with a keytab and add it to the root .k5login file

   (I’ve been warned against this since it effectively gives anyone with root access on *server2* root access on any of the other servers)
3. Create a new kerberos principal with a keytab and add it to the correct groups

   (This is my proposed plan)

The problem is that the ldap db and some other sensitive files are not group readable. However, the group and owner are always the same.

`-rw------- 1 ldap ldap    40960 Feb 11 10:57 cn.bdb`

Are there any problems with changing these files to be group readable?